# Chef: Install package in Centos 7

Tags: chef-infra

I'd like to install net-tools on my centos/7 node.

I've took a look on related `net-tools` chef cookbooks available, and there's nothing specific to get that.

What and how could I install the latest `net-tools` package version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a `package` resource, like:

```
package 'net-tools' do
  action :install
end
```

Or better:

```
package 'net-tools'
```

And if you are planning to apply the recipe on several OS, you can use [ohai attributes](https://docs.chef.io/ohai.html) like this:

```
case node['platform']
  when 'centos'
    package 'net-utils'
  when 'other_os'
    package 'other_package_name'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a normal `package` resource? Something so simple wouldn't justify a community cookbook.

Comment: Please, could you provide a sample stuff code in order to test it?

Comment: You should probably run though the basic Chef tutorials at learn.chef.io, since that covers the process of writing a recipe.